# How to create one more AppDelegate in Xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, universal, appdelegate

I am working in iPhone application, Using Xcode 4.3.2 tool to develop it, Using universal application to create this application, but only one Appdelegate (i am using this appdelegate for iPhone) show in the project navigator, but i want another one Appdelegate for iPad, How to create this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

Screen shots for your reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: iPad and iPhone targets typically share the same app delegate you just check which idiom to determine what views you want to display.

Comment: Wow. I don't think you can do this, but I look forward to reading that I'm wrong. (Also, great question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code may be help you

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPad *) delegate;
else
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *) delegate;
```

Comment: in that class where you want to use delegate class method or function